# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar este código de JavaScript con tan solo presionar un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Quiero hacer un botón en HTML y cuando la presione ejecute este código de JavaScript. Alguien que me ayude a cómo hacer eso?

```js
(function minions() {
  'use strict';

  var botMessage = "Mensaje";
  var numberOfMessagesToSend = 1; //number of times to repeat
  var millisecondsBetweenSend = 3000; //number of milliseconds (example: 5000 = 5 seconds) (example: 60000 = 1 minute) (example: 300000 = 5 minutes)

  function sendMessage(botMessage) {
    document.getElementById("chat_textbox").value = botMessage;
    var e = new Event("keydown");
    e.key = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
    e.which = 13;
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
  }

  var numberOfMessagesSent = 0;

  function repeatMessage(botMessage, numberOfMessagesToSend, millisecondsBetweenSend) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      sendMessage(botMessage);
      numberOfMessagesSent++;
      if (numberOfMessagesSent < numberOfMessagesToSend) {
        repeatMessage(botMessage, numberOfMessagesToSend, millisecondsBetweenSend);
      }
    }, millisecondsBetweenSend);
  }

  repeatMessage(botMessage, numberOfMessagesToSend, millisecondsBetweenSend);

})();
```

Extra: Este código es para un juego que estoy haciendo estilo agar.io y necesito de su ayuda ya que no sé mucho de JavaScript, esto es extra porque stackoverflow me lo pidió.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada debes eliminar la auto-ejecución de tu función eliminando el paréntesis principal de la siguiente manera:

```js
function minions() {
        'use strict';

        var botMessage = "Mensaje";
        var numberOfMessagesToSend = 1; //number of times to repeat
        var millisecondsBetweenSend = 3000; //number of milliseconds (example: 5000 = 5 seconds) (example: 60000 = 1 minute) (example: 300000 = 5 minutes)

        function sendMessage(botMessage) {
            document.getElementById("chat_textbox").value = botMessage;
            var e = new Event("keydown");
            e.key = 13;
            e.keyCode = 13;
            e.which = 13;
            window.dispatchEvent(e);
            window.dispatchEvent(e);
        }

        var numberOfMessagesSent = 0;

        function repeatMessage(botMessage, numberOfMessagesToSend, millisecondsBetweenSend) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            sendMessage(botMessage);
            numberOfMessagesSent++;
            if (numberOfMessagesSent < numberOfMessagesToSend) {
                repeatMessage(botMessage, numberOfMessagesToSend, millisecondsBetweenSend);
            }
            }, millisecondsBetweenSend);
        }

        repeatMessage(botMessage, numberOfMessagesToSend, millisecondsBetweenSend);
    }
```

ahora solo creas un botón que llame la función esto lo puedes hacer de dos formas.
la primera:

```html
<button onclick="minions()">Boton</button>
```

o la segunda:

```js
document.getElementById('call-function').onclick = function() {
        minions();
    }
```

```html
<button id="call-function">Boton</button>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Si me funcionó

Comment: @EsaelDeveloper si esta respuesta te sirvió para resolver la pregunta, por favor, márcala como aceptada y considera darle un voto positivo. Lee sobre [qué hacer cuando alguien contesta tu pregunta](/help/someone-answers) y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).